# Swift 3 array var no longer mutable

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm migrating a project from Swift 2.2 to 3.0, and I'm getting an error when concatenating arrays.  Here's what used to work:

```
var x : [(index:Int, value:Float)] = []

for i in 0..<n {
    x += [(i, Float(i))]
}
```

throws:

```
Left side of mutating operator isn't mutable: 'x' is immutable
```

In this case it is not clear to me why an array declared as a `var` would ever be immutble.

I have searched the Swift 3 documentation, and it is not clear to me which rules have changed which would cause these errors, or how to know when an array var will be immutable vs mutable.

Comment: should you not be appending in arrays instead og += ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems it's the array-type that makes a mess of things, you need:

```
var x: [(index:Int, value:Float)] = []

for i in 0..<n {
    x += [(index: i, value: Float(i))]
}
```

And those array-elements *really* look like they should be a struct of some type...

Comment: thanks it works!  In this case the error generated was totally unrelated to the actual issue.

Comment: That _is_ true, it's the kind of stuff to make your head implode.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried on XCode 8 Playground

```
class MyClass {
var positions : [Float] = []
var values : [Float] = []

func myFunc(p:Float, v:Float) {
    positions.append(p)
    self.values.append(v)
   }
}
```

Its working for swift 3.

Comment: Thanks - turns out this issue was created by an optional being added elsewhere by the migration assistant.  The error message was just totally unrelated...